# Prevention of deleting some text in EditText

Tags: android

I want user input text after a text that I set in EditText already and this text can not be deleted by users.

For example, I set text "Name : " inside EditText then users input their names after "Name : "

Comment: Why do you need this? The way you may want to use is putting a TextView left of the EditText

Comment: I decided to put the name of each EditText inside EditText. 
I'm trying the new way.

Comment: you could use a text change listener for the EditText and if the amount of letters in the EditText < the amount of letters of e.g. "Name : " you set "Name :" again. That would work but its really a hack.

Comment: @aratn0n [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820258/permanent-hint-in-edittext) may help you. It's not entirely pretty, but that's because EditTexts aren't really meant to do what you want.

Comment: @aratn0n : you can  archive it very easy using TextWatcher .

Comment: @David Could you me an example of code ?

Comment: @A--C : i think hit is deleted when EditText get focus

Comment: @all: hint is not what aratnOn is searching for. the link given by A - C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820258/permanent-hint-in-edittext should give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching this the wrong way.

The functionality you want is to combine the behavior of a `TextView` (non-mutable text) with an `EditText` (mutable text). You do this by *acutally putting a TextView on an EditText*.

Using a relative layout,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:paddingLeft="54dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="Name:" />
```

This will result in:

[image]

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Quoting from my own answer: "Using a relative Layout" :-). But seriously, is there a drawback to this approach I am missing? I know you are well-versed in Android Development, so if I'm doing something silly please correct my ways.

Comment: :im also with your solution

Comment: we have two way to solve current issue First using your answer and second by using TextWatcher

Answer (score 1):

Follows some basic idea do it by using the [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html).

```
static class InnerFieldLabelHelper implements InputFilter, View.OnTouchListener {

    private final CharSequence label;
    private EditText editText;

    InnerFieldLabelHelper(CharSequence label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        CharSequence result;
        if (dest.length() < label.length()) {
            result = label.subSequence(label.length() - 2, label.length());
        } else if (dstart >= label.length() - 1) {
            result = source;
        } else {
            result = "";
        }

        resetPositionIfNecessary();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (view.equals(editText)) {
            result = resetPositionIfNecessary();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean resetPositionIfNecessary() {
        boolean result = false;
        if (editText.length() >= label.length() && editText.getSelectionStart() < label.length()) {
            editText.setSelection(label.length());
            editText.requestFocus();
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void configure(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.editText.setText(label);
        this.editText.setSelection(label.length());

        this.editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ this });
        this.editText.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}
```